# Access FreeMarker map where the key is in a variable

Tags: xml, apache, freemarker

I have an Apache FreeMarker "map" variable, and I need to access an element in the map.  The problem is that the "key" of the element I'm looking for is stored in a variable itself.  Consider the following map:

```
<#assign mymap = {"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2"}>
```

Now I can access the map easily with something like this:

```
${mymap.key1}
```

And this works fine.  My problem is that "key1" is contained in a variable like this:

```
<#assign keyname = "key1">
<-- Now I want to access the map via whatever key is in the variable keyname -->
${mymap.${keyname}}
```

Unfortunately, the above syntax is illegal.  I guess FreeMarker isn't smart enough to perform nested interpolations.  So, how do I accomplish this?  A cursory examination of the documentation doesn't really seem to talk about this kind of scenario.  It seems like it would be pretty common though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [alternative syntax](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_var_hash) for hash

```
 mymap[keyname]
```

> There is an alternative syntax if we want to specify the subvariable name with an expression: book["title"]. In the square brackets you can give any expression as long as it evaluates to a string. So with this data-model you can also read the title with book[test]. More examples; these are all equivalent: book.author.name, book["author"].name, book.author["name"], book["author"]["name"].